# Integral of Bessel functions times $x^3$ (diferent eigenvalues)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

I'm having a course on partial diferential equation solving, and we are currently going through cylindrical coordinates problems.

I'm trying to solve the heat equation for a cylinder with fixed surface temperatures like shown here:
[Infinite semi-cylinder with diferent temperatures fixed in each surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw6u9.png)
Since there are no heat sources, we have to deal with a Laplace problem such that:
$$
\Delta u = 0
$$
With this CC:
$$
u(ρ= ρ_0) = T_3\\
u(z=0) = u(z=L) = T_1\\
u(\phi = 0) = u(\phi=\pi) = T_2
$$
So in order to solve this, we have been taught to use variable separation and simplify the operator making Sturm-Lioville problems in the proper directions.
Then:
$$
u(\rho, \phi, z) = R(\rho)\Phi(\phi)Z(z)
$$

And plugging this into the laplace operator and dividing by u:

$$
\frac{1}{R}\Big(\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dR }{d\rho} + \frac{d^2R }{d\rho^2}\Big) + \frac{1}{\Phi \rho^2}\frac{d^2\Phi }{d\phi^2} + \frac{d^2Z }{dz^2}\frac{1}{Z} = 0
$$

Then we will use the linearity of the operator to find the solution by adding the solution of 2 more simple problems. First we make the change of variables such that the contourn of the chosen "favourite" direction has homogenous condition, like shown here:
[Separating problem in 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWUnr.png)

The thing is that the teacher has stated that we should always try to solve the problems by using orthogonal φ functions, that is, taking for both problems φ with homogenous conditions and orthogonal function:

$$
\frac{d^2\Phi }{d\phi^2} + m^2\phi = 0\\
\Phi(0) = \Phi (\pi) = 0
$$
And aplying the CC for the angular direction we find sinusoidal functions.

However I still don't know why we can't find the solution using in both problems the prefered direction Z.
So that, for the problem with $\rho$ also with homogenous conditions we have:
The CC:
$$
v(ρ= ρ_0) = T_3-T_1\\
v(z=0) = u(z=L) = 0\\
v(\phi = 0) = u(\phi=\pi) = T_2-T_1
$$
We state that:
$$
\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dR }{d\rho} + \frac{d^2R }{d\rho^2} = λR\\
\frac{d^2Z }{dz^2} = μZ
$$
The first one is satified by the first order Bessel equation and the second one is a sine function.

The eigenvalues of each are found using the CC:
$$
R(\rho_0) = J_0(\sqrt{λ_n}\rho_0)=0\\
Z(L) = \sin(\sqrt{\mu}L) = 0
$$

Substituying in the laplacian:
$$
\Big(\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{d^2\Phi_n }{d\phi^2} - (λ+μ)\Phi_n\Big)J_0(\sqrt{λ_n}\rho)sin(\sqrt{\mu}z)=0
$$

And if we multiply by $\rho^3J_0(\sqrt{λ_n'}\rho)sin(\sqrt{\mu'})$ and integrate from 0 to $\rho_0$  and from 0 to L in z we get a term proportional to $δ_{nn'}δ_{\mu\mu'}$ (from orthogonality of $J_0$ and sine function) plus the integral I'm concerned about:

$$
\int_{0}^{ρ_{0}}ρ^3J_0(xλ_n)J_0(xλ_{n'})dρ
$$

Is this integral proportional to $\delta_{nn'}$? If not why. I cannot find a way to prove it. The reason this is so important, is that, if it is not proportional to $\delta_{nn'}$, then the equation for $\phi$ won't be resoluble since we won't have *one* equation for each eigenvalue $λ_n$.

Best regards!

Comment: Well, Bessel function and the aplication its orthogonality is highly used in PDE solving. Most important, the problem that I'm having is finding the solution for the heat equation for a infinite semi-cylinder, with its bounds set at diferent temperatures.

Comment: That's not the problem, we solve it like that in class. The problem is why the integral is not proportional to kronecker delta i.e. orthogonal

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it's a semi-cylinder and not an actual cylinder. That's a really weird geometry to consider...

Comment: So are you asking "why can't you do the splitting such that $u$ on the top and bottom are always zero, by subtracting off $T_1$ initially?" or "why can't you do the splitting so that $u$ on the side is always zero, by subtracting off $T_3$ initially?"?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking why I cant do he splitting such that u is 0 on the top and bottom always. The main point is we have to prove that the integral I show is not proportional to a kronecker delta, or we won't be able to find the coeficients